# How to use htaccess to rewrite url to html anchor tag (#)

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, uri-fragment

I have a situation where I want to take the following URL:

/1/john

and have it redirect using Apache's htaccess file to go to

/page.php?id=1&name=john#john

so that it goes to an html anchor with the name of john.

I've found a lot of reference to escaping special characters, and to adding the [NE] flag so that the redirect ignores the # sign, but these don't work. For example, adding [NE,R] means that the URL just appears in the browser address as the original: http://example.com/page.php?id=1&name=john#john.

Answer (score 28):

This is possible using **[NE] flag** (noescape).

By default, special characters, such as & and ?, for example, will be converted to their hexcode equivalent. Using the [NE] flag prevents that from happening.

More info http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_ne

Answer (score 6):

**You can do one of these things, but not both.**

You can use the [NE] flag to signify to Apache not to escape the '#' character, but for the redirect to work, you have to specify an absolute URL to redirect to, not simply a relative page. Apache cannot do the scrolling of the window down to the anchor for you. But the browser will, if you redirect to an absolute URL.

Comment: To the original poster: indicate an answer as correct to resolve this.

Comment: Hmm .. with Apache 2.4.25, I'm specify a relative page and still getting an external redirect to an anchor tag. Maybe things have changed since 2013?  In a <Directory> section, `RewriteBase "/"` then `RewriteRule ^services/?$ #services [L,R=301,NE]` is working for me. Which is nice if I don't have to re-do the rules when converting to https.

Answer (score 3):

What you want to do, can be accomplished with URL rewriting, or, more specifically, URL beautification.

[I just quickly found this well explained blog post for you](http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net/techblog/article/beautify_urls/), I hope it can help you out with the [learning to rewrite URLs-part](http://perishablepress.com/press/2006/01/10/stupid-htaccess-tricks/).

As for the `#`-thing (expecting that you now know what I'm talking about), I don't see a problem in passing the same variable to the rewritten URL twice. Like: (notice the last part of the first line)

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)$  /$1/$2/#$2 [R]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/$ /index.php?page=$1&subpage=$2
```

Though, you'll have to escape the `#`-part, and [it seems](http://www.webmasterworld.com/apache/4035516.htm) that it can be done this way:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)$  /$1/$2/\%23$2 [R,NE]
```

BTW, URL rewriting is not *that* hard (but can become complicated, and I'm not an expert), but Google can help a lot along the way.

Comment: Hi Sune, thanks for the response. I don't think what I'm trying to do is possible, however. See response on this page from nikc.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do an internal redirect to an anchor. (Just think about it: how would Apache scroll down to the anchor?) Your link should pointo to `/1/john#john`. Anchors aren't part of the request uri.

Comment: I'm verifying this in practice and believe you're correct. The browser interprets anchors and scrolls down to the correct point in the page; an Apache redirect is not able to do this because the redirected-to URI isn't passed to the browser.