# .htaccess rewrite links as anchor links

Tags: jquery, .htaccess, url-rewriting, anchor

Is there an htaccess rewrite I can deploy which will make `http://example.com/about` display the same location on the page as `http://example.com/#about`? If not, can I do it with jQuery?

Comment: Check [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2872490/how-to-use-htaccess-to-rewrite-url-to-html-anchor-tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2872490/how-to-use-htaccess-to-rewrite-url-to-html-anchor-tag) and [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2285193/htaccess-redirect-to-page-with-anchor-link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2285193/htaccess-redirect-to-page-with-anchor-link)

Answer (score 0):

Here, I figured it out. It's not perfect (it redirects to the anchor so you see it in the url) but it works for me:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)$  /\#$1 [R,NE]
```

If you were using this, `http://example.com/about` would become `http://example.com/#about`.